# How to move (or copy) blobs between containers in Azure Blob Storage using java

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

I have a java application which I use to upload some artifacts to Azure Blob Storage. Now I am trying to move these files from one container to another. Below is a sample code on what I do right now.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
  BlobContainerClient releaseContainer = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(RELEASE_CONTAINER);
  BlobContainerClient backupContainer = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(BACKUP_CONTAINER);

  for (BlobItem blobItem : releaseContainer.listBlobs()) {
     BlobClient destBlobClient = backupContainer.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
     BlobClient sourceBlobClient = releaseContainer.getBlobClient(blobItem.getName());
     destBlobClient.copyFromUrl(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl());
     sourceBlobClient.delete();
  }
```

Is there a more straight forward way to do this?
Also if this is the way to do it how can I delete the old file? sourceBlobClient.delete() doesn't work now.

Comment: Do you mean that all the above code samples can be executed successfully, but the delete operation fails?

Comment: Could you please tell me what version of your `jdk` and `azure-storage-blob` are?

Comment: Hi Frank, actually the delete works now and that is not a problem. But I still think there must be a more elegant way to move or copy files.

Also I am using java 8 with azure-storage-blob 12.8.0

Comment: Does `copyFromUrl` method works well with you when trying to copy blob that way? It always fails with me when I try to copy a blob to another location. It worked only when I gave it a URL from an external server. @KosalaLakshitha

Answer (score 1):

You can move files using the `rename` method from. [`azure-storage-file-datalake`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.2.0) java client.

```
DataLakeServiceClient storageClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder().endpoint(endpoint).credential(credential).buildClient();
DataLakeFileSystemClient dataLakeFileSystemClient = storageClient.getFileSystemClient("storage");
DataLakeFileClient fileClient = dataLakeFileSystemClient.getFileClient("src/path");
fileClient.rename("storage", "dest/path");
```

method documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.datalake.datalakefileclient.rename?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_file_datalake_DataLakeFileClient_rename_java_lang_String_java_lang_String)

Note that the `azure-storage-file-datalake` java client gives you great options to deal with your storage account as a filesystem. But take care there's no way to copy files there.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar discussion in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117069/how-to-move-azure-blob-from-one-storage-container-to-another-using-java-rest) can you refer to the suggestion and let me know the status
Additional information: Have you check [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs) tool, one of the best to tool to move/copy data

I see you have posted the similar query in the [Q&A Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/82770/how-to-move-blobs-between-azure-blob-storage-conta.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `copyFromUrl()` just triggers a copy job and returns its ID. You can wait for the job to finish and check the response code with `.beginCopy()`:

```java
SyncPoller<BlobCopyInfo, Void> poller = blobClient.beginCopy("<url-to-blob>", Duration.ofSeconds(1));
poller.waitForCompletion();
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/README.md#copy-a-blob

API Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob

Of course you can also configure the retry for this action.

It's also a good idea to check the checksums for large files. See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/blob/FileTransferExample.java